# Controlling VirtualBox from the Command Line

Tags: virtualbox

When I try to start my new VM I get this error.

```
server1@server1:~$ VBoxManage startvm roy --type=headless
Waiting for VM "roy" to power on...  
    VBoxManage: error: VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED)     
    VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

Comment: I am running dl360 u1 server

Comment: You need to enable virtualization in bios.